# move two different file types with same name into a new folder with same name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

assume that we have a number of video files (*.mp4) along with their subtitle files (*.srt) in a folder, i want to loop through all files, if two files of type (mp4 & srt) have the same name, i want to move them into a new folder having the same name of either of them. if the folder exist, then just move if not then create a new one.

i used two approaches to get the list of files

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.mp4 *.srt) do (
     comparison here )
pause
```

and

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b *mp4* *srt*') do (
comparison procedure )
pause
```

i tried to store the each file name of extension (mp4) in a variable to check it against all the other files that have the extension (srt) but that did not work, i can work with text tokens with no problems

any ideas ?

Comment: What do you want to do if the folder exists and the files already exist in the folder?

Comment: just skip the files and move to the next ones

Comment: I would loop through all `*.mp4` files first, then check whether an equally named `*.srt` file exists, like this: `for %%F in (*.mp4) do if exist "%%~nF.srt" ( ... )` (the same works also with the `for /F`/`dir` version)

Comment: @aschipfl....good idea to get the name part of %%F and add srt to it, let's try that

Answer (score 3):

This should get what you need.  Using the FOR variable modifiers is the key to getting done what you need.

```
@echo off

for %%G in (*.srt) do (
    IF EXIST "%%~nG.mp4" (
        MD "%%~nG" 2>nul
        IF NOT EXIST "%%~nG\%%~nG.mp4" move "%%~nG.mp4" "%%~nG"
        IF NOT EXIST "%%~nG\%%~G" move "%%~G" "%%~nG"
    )
)
```

Comment: can you explain the "2>nul" part ? does that mean if a folder already exists then the output will be forwarded to nul wich is nothing basically

Comment: Just suppresses the error message if the folder already exists.

Comment: thanks @squashman... i guess my brain doesn't work as it used to be lol

Comment: Wound it not be smart to nest the two `if exist` queries and do both moves only in case none of the files (`.mp4`, `.srt`) exist in the target location? anyway, +1...